# Magento. How to change shipping method before save order?

Tags: magento

I must change shipping method before saving order if (condition) is true, and don't change it if false. I tried out function `checkout_type_onepage_save_order($observer).`

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
```

but it doesn't work.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to accomplish with this

Comment: i need to change shipping method to free shipping. if (condition) is true the customer have 100% discount on shipping.

Comment: you can use cart rules for that no need to develop another bicycle for this

Comment: i have a very hard condition.

Comment: You are from Estonia. Do you speak russian?

Comment: hard is relative and if you ask questions here try to enlighten what you are after and what are your conditions then it is possible to suggest or answer your question

Comment: Condision is based on a local Module. I can write a function, which return a boolean variable. And if this variable is true I must set 100% discount on shipping. Can I do this with using "Cart Rules"?

Comment: who knows as you are not explaining nothing about the condition you are implementing

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with things not saving properly in checkout, e.g. shipping address. I think you have to save the quote object again, but I cannot remember for sure.

However, why don't you write your own shipping module? This is the place for doing it properly and within your own module you can put together all the rules you need to set the price to what it needs to be, plus the frontend label, e.g. 'Free!' if a zero price is calculated.

Here is a tutorial that has worked very well for me in the past:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method